# Google Apps Script to send email notification, if the email from an expected sender is not received every 1 hour

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have managed to get email notification alert if I have not received an expected email in past XX day.
By following the guidelines given in - http://baumbach.com/google-script/
It is working as expected.

Here is the javascript code-

```
function SearchEmail() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
// "in:all " searches trash and spam email folders. Remove "in:all " + to only search all mail and inbox
var gsearch = "in:all " + "from:(" + data[i][1] + ") to:(" + data[i][2] + ") subject:(" + data[i][3] + ") newer_than:" + data[i][4] + "d";
var threads = GmailApp.search(gsearch, 0, 1);
if (threads.length == 0) {
var emailSubject = "No email in " + data[i][4] + " days: - " + data[i][5];
var emailText = "Note: " + data[i][5] + "\r\n\r\nSearch was: " + gsearch;
var emailTo = data[i][0];
MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, emailSubject, emailText);
        }
    }
}
```

But, What I want is, to get email notification alert if I have not received an expected email in past 1 Hour and not days.

Can anyone tell me how to do this and where should I change the code??
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### EDIT

In the guide from the [link](http://baumbach.com/google-script/) you provided and in your code, the date used to query the messages from Gmail comes from the linked spreadsheet you have, so this part would be set by you.

To query the message the code uses the `gsearch` variable which is formatted by the `q` parameter [guidelines](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering) using the [Gmail search operators](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190) and inserting data in the query from the `data` variable which is obtained from using the [getDataRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) and [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) methods to your sheets. For what I see in the search operators, there's no option to query the messages by time, the minimum is 1 day.

Also, they explain they set up a [time driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to execute the `SearchEmail` function once a day. For this part you can use the [everyHours](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#everyhoursn) method to create a trigger to execute the function once every hour. Run the below function once in order to create the trigger:

```
function createTimeTriger1hour() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("SearchEmail")
    .timeBased()
    .everyHours(1)
    .create();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This code provided by you runs the javascript for every 1 hour . But, what I wanted to know is - how to fetch the hours from spreadsheet instead of day and use the script to manipulate hours and not days. Hope I make sense. So basically I need javascript code that evaluates the mail for past 1 hour and not past 1 day.

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide more explanation

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This was informative :-)